# Was this character's mistake accidental?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

Towards the end of Captain America: Civil War,

> while Falcon, Rhodey, and Stark are fighting in midair, Vision shoots Rhodey directly in the reactor that powers his suit, shattering it.

He seems torn up about this later and says he was distracted.

> Was the mistake he made missing a shot, or did he hit Rhodey intentionally out of emotion? Rhodey had blasted Wanda moments before, and Vision is both fond of her and apparently displeased with the entire ordeal.

Notably,

> He seems to make no attempt to arrest Rhodey's fall.

I am curious whether there is anything beyond the film that sheds light on this (written work, scripts, interviews, similar moments from the comics as a long shot).

Answer (score 21):

### Paul Bettany, the actor behind Vision (and JARVIS), explained that it was (to him, at least) a thoughtless mistake.

He [explained this to Entertainment Weekly](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/05/09/captain-america-civil-war-vision-paul-bettany-scarlet-witch)

> “You see him in the first movie, he’s born. He’s omnipotent, but he’s incredibly naïve. And in this movie he’s kind of beginning to take a more paternal role in the superhero family, and he’s growing at an exponential rate, **and by the end of the movie he has a real emotion and real human reaction and he makes first mistake that he’s ever made.**”
>
> [...]
>
> “What happened there is that his judgment was clouded there by real love and affection,” says Bettany. “**And he responded in a quick and thoughtless way**.… I really love that the moral compass of the movie is this synthetic person who’s trying to figure out what it means to be human. It’s a neat idea, you know?”

However, Bettany seems to be referring more to the fact that he fired the blast at all, something he knew was potentially lethal in a battle where everyone was pulling their punches. In the scene, Wanda had just been hit, and Vision reacts impulsively, missing and accidentally downing not only a friend, but a friend on his own side of the battle.

Why, specifically, he doesn't try to slow Rhodey's fall is left to interpretation right now, but Vision, who is becoming more and more human (including now beginning to fall in love with Wanda, who had just been hit), my guess is that he was stunned by his own actions and what he had done, and froze up briefly.

Comment: Upvoted because great background, though Bettany never clarified whether the "quick and thoughtless" mistake was actually accidental. Those quotes could all easily apply to an impulsive, intentional act.

Comment: My interpretation was that Vision shot a quick blast and returned to tending to Wanda, possibly not even noticing the results of his action.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_(Marvel_Comics), the Vision flies through density shifting. If he had tried to catch Rhodes while he fell, he would pass through him, possibly injuring him more. It's rather evident that it was a mistake, as he was aiming for Falcon, but he (Falcon) moved out of the way.

Comment: This explains why he may not try to catch him, but is an incomplete answer as it does not address whether or not the attack was accidental or not.

Comment: It's rather evident that it was a mistake, as he was aiming for Falcon, but he (Falcon) moved out of the way.

Comment: Does that mean that MCU Vision can't fly with any payload but himself?

Answer (score 2):

Good question. It appears in the movie

> that the Vision was aiming for something else (I believe it was the Quinjet), and in the time that the beam needed to travel, Rhodey saw it, and moved in front of it.

This might have coincided with

> the fact that Rhodey had just hit Wanda beforehand, and Vision is very fond of Wanda and her powers.

All in all, it may have been influenced by emotion. Perhaps that last part was.

Comment: He appeared to be aiming at falcon, a direct aim.  Falcon collapsed his wings to move out of the way... the next in line was Warmachine.

Comment: He was aiming at Falcon, at Rhodey's request.  Rhodey requested support because Falcon was right on his tail.  Falcon dodged the shot, and it instead struck Rhodey.  There's no indication that it was intentional (on anyone's part), it's just an inevitable effect of using super powers in a large-scale fight.  A missed attack can hit an ally, especially one who had been nearby the target.

Comment: What are you trying to quote here with your quote formatting?